# Can a ListView be displyed programatically without an XML layout?

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout

i have an activity in which i want to show a ListView with 2 simple string items. i tried it two different ways (w/xml layout and w/o xml layout) - both ways i add the 2 items but  eventually the items are only visible in the version that creates the list w/xml layout. why is that?

the xml layout, list_view_custom_layout.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <ListView android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The code that uses the XML (and works well) does this:

```
activity.setContentView(R.layout.list_view_custom_layout); //this must be done here
listView=(ListView)activity.findViewById(R.id.ListView);
```

The code that doesn't use the XML is identical except instead of the the above 2 lines 
it does this (which seems it should be equivalent):

```
LinearLayout customLayout=new LinearLayout(activity);
//customLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
customLayout.setLayoutParams(layout);


ListView listView=new ListView(activity);
customLayout.addView(listView,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

aren't the 2 equivalent and if so, why are the items that are added (via an adapter)
displayed only for the first method (in which the xml layout is used)?
thanks

Comment: Use Hierarchy Viewer to examine both cases and see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 3):

try this..

```
public class VersionActivity extends Activity {

    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> aR;
    String[] str = new String[] { "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5",
            "item6" };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        listView = new ListView(this);
        aR = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, str);
        listView.setAdapter(aR);
        linearLayout.addView(listView);
        setContentView(linearLayout);
    }
}
```

Comment: this will throw this exception `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'`